# CMS Mailer (PHP) replying letter, missing data

Tags: php, content-management-system, mailer, reply

I am using CMS Mailer for E-mail sending in my site (PHP based module).
It worked perfectly till I changed my server and also location of whole website.

It's working now, but seems there appeared **bugs** like: 
 missing reply data for people i.e. who want to answer to my letter , they need to enter it with their hands, but normaly it must be filled automaticly.

Normaly, when you press "Reply" to letter, it brings letter form, with filled fields (To, Subject...), but in my case "**To**" is missing.

I searched code (which wasn't modified from time, when mailer worked perfectly, till now), information for reply is hold in "header". I also checked server mail setting, chmod. So, where could be a problem, when only server place was changed, but no source code edited, event latest CMS Mailer version was downloaded in process of seaching problem?

Comment: Somehow it is working with Gmail, but when users use something like "Outlook", there is problem.

Comment: You need to give more information than just what doesn't work anymore. What was your previous server? What is the current server? What database you're using? And what do you mean "changed my server"? Changed from Apache to IIS? Did server OS change? Some info like that..

Comment: I changed physical server and PHP version (to newer), except that nothing have changed (just web moved from one place, to another). Web service, OS haven't changed.

Comment: Well then, if nothing changed but php version, I suggest you check your php module with your current and previous php versions. It's next to impossible to tell you what's wrong when I can't see the code.